# get current logged in users and Account records on a click of button on a detail page using LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

Can someone please help me on how to get current logged in userName and Account records on a click of button on a detail page using LWC. Below is my code.

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import USER_ID from '@salesforce/user/Id'; // impoting USER id

const ACCOUNT_FIELDS = [
    'Account.Name',
    'Account.Phone'
];
const USER_FIELDS = [
    'User.UserName'
];
export default class testAcc extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track record;
    @track error;
    @track userId;
    @track userRecordId;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: ACCOUNT_FIELDS })
        accountData({error, data}) {
            if(data) {
                this.record = data;
                this.userRecordId = USER_ID;
        } 
        else if(error) {
            let error = 'Something went wrong, Please contact your Manager';
                if ( error.body.message) {
                    this.error = error.body.message;
                }
                //this.showToast('Error!', this.error, 'Error');
        }
    }

    @wire(getRecord , { recordId: '$userRecordId', fields: USER_FIELDS })
        userData({error, data}) {
            //alert('userId'+this.USER_ID);
            if(data) {
                this.userId = data.fields.Username.value;
            }
        else if(error) {
            let error = 'Something went wrong, Please contact your Manager';
                if ( error.body.message) {
                    this.error = error.body.message;
                }
                //this.showToast('Error!', this.error, 'Error');

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: markup? also are you getting any error or exception?

Comment: I am actually trying to navigate to a URL based on the values fetched. So I don't need anything to be displayed.